# Wordpress+ACF - Filtering through multiselect options in a repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering, advanced-custom-fields, ajaxform

I’m integrating a form of $_POST method with ajax filtering, to filter through repeater filed in all posts. so i’m not filtering posts (always all posts are displayed), just filtering inside each post.

the repeater field contain two sub fields – multiselect and Wysiwyg Editor.
Now, according to what the user selected in the front-end form, if it’s equal to a post multiselect values, it should display the Wysiwyg Editor field of the matching multiselect.

I have this working without multiselect. but with the multiselect, i can’t get a conditional to be ALL selected filters values, to be the exact match of ALL multiselect values.
So the result i get, as it is in a foreach loop, is multiple Wysiwyg Editor fields.

I tried a lot of things, this is an example code of one of them:
(‘cond_options’ – multiselect
‘description’ – Wysiwyg Editor’
‘ weather/sky/night’ – filters values)

```
if ( have_rows('cond-repeater') ):
   while (have_rows('cond-repeater') ) : the_row();

        $select_options = get_sub_field('cond_options');
        $selectdesc = get_sub_field('description');

            if( $select_options ):
               foreach( $select_options as $select ):
                    if( isset( $_POST['weather'] ) && $_POST['weather'] && isset( $_POST['sky'] ) && $_POST['sky'] && isset( $_POST['night'] ) && $_POST['night'] == $select  ){
                        echo $selectdesc;
                    }  
            echo $select; //just to see the output of selected options
                 endforeach; 

            endif; 

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: If you want to check if _all_ of your conditions are true, then the output does not belong into the foreach loop, but after it - only then will you be able to tell whether all conditions were true; while you are in the loop, you don’t even know that yet. Use a boolean flag, that you initialite with true before the loop, if any condition does not match, then set it to false, and break out of the loop. Handle output based on the value of that flag after the loop.

Comment: What values do you have in your multiple select acf field?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your data and the actual end result you are trying to achieve. I have put together something that might help steer you in the right direction.

The main thing to point out is the use of `in_array`, with this we can check if a value exists in the multiple select without having to loop through it with a foreach.

Let me know if this helps.

```php
$_weather = !empty( $_POST[ 'weather' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'weather' ] : null;
$_sky = !empty( $_POST[ 'sky' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'sky' ] : null;
$_night = !empty( $_POST[ 'night' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'night' ] : null;

if ( have_rows('cond-repeater') ) {
    while ( have_rows('cond-repeater') ) {
        the_row();

        if ( $options = get_sub_field( 'cond_options' ) ) {

            // Check payload includes all required parameters
            if ( $_weather && $_sky && $_night ) {

                // Check if all parameters exist in the multiselect value
                if ( in_array( $_weather, $options ) && in_array( $_sky, $options ) && in_array( $_night, $options ) ) {
                    echo get_sub_field( 'description' );
                } else {
                    echo $select; // Warning: Undefined variable!
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried before using in_array but will check again with your base and will let you know. Thanks!